Как узнать на что MySQL тратит все 100% ресурсов процессора?
В течении дня сайт нормально работает, но в одно и тоже время MySQL начинает есть ресурсы(100% процессора) и просто роняет его. В чем может быть проблема?
cat mysql

Показывает
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Содержимое etc/mysql/conf.d/:

mysql.cnf

[mysql]
max_allowed_packet = 64M


mysqldump.cnf

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 64M


mysqld.cnf

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log


mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

[mysqld_safe]
syslog

Содержимое /var/log/mysql/error.log:


Ну а чё-нить из https://signoz.io/blog/mysql-monitoring-tools/ тестил?
